# redirect sub traffic to homepage in single page application

Tags: backbone.js, web, asp.net-web-api, single-page-application

how you would redirect all subpages traffic to homepage in your spa.i know it s server related is there any graceful way other than rewriting rules in server.

my case it s iis, and servers side code is written in ms technology.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an MVC app you can do a Response.Redirect or call another action method on the server side in a controller method, you do not need to resort to URL rewriting.